# iOS, support retina display

Tags: ios, retina-display

When supporting retina, and non-retina displays you would provide the `image.png` & `image@X2.png` with relating resolutions.

I understand that iOS will decide which image to use based on the user's device. However, I'm using the images via code, not storyboard.

```
self.imagePortrait = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

Even though I have not specified `image@X2.png`, will iOS make use of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case yes. UIImage's `-imageNamed:` is smart enough to choose the correct resource. (And note that the suffix is `@2x`, not `@X2`.)

[From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:):

> If the screen has a scale of 2.0, this method first searches for an
>   image file with the same filename with an @2x suffix appended to it.

Other methods (like `-initWithContentsOfFile:`) do not have these smarts built in.